# Get an Empty Column from a table when filter condition fetches empty in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, filter, where-clause

I have two tables `table1(id,name,type)` and `table2(id,source,destination)`

When I run query

```
SELECT
    name,
    source,
    destination
FROM
    table1,
    table2
WHERE
    table1.id=table2.id
```

If there's no id matching between two tables, can I still get empty column for **source and destination** .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you basically want an `OUTER JOIN` and remember to always use the explicit `ANSI JOIN` syntax and not the implicit comma syntax for joins.Also use proper table aliases to avoid ambiguity.

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    t2.source,
    t2.destination
FROM
    table1 t1 left outer join
    table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Seems good let me try this and update, can I do the same for more than two tables, when T1 has to join with t2 and also t1 has to join with t3.. and what if for only t2 and t3 tables i want empty columns, where as  for other tables it exits and t1  primary key is used as filter , i dont wantempty columns there. there it should be direct

Comment: @JohnHumanyun : Sure. Read more about SQL Joins and outer joins in particular to understand better.